# Laravel Query Scope in Loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scope, eloquent

I have a loop that runs a query and builds an associative array, one key/value pair for each result set. What's happening is that the scopes keep piling up as the loop iterates.

```
<?php

foreach ($master_asset_categories as $master_category) {
    $master_assets_this_category = $asset_query->group($master_category->id)->get();
    $master_asset_array[$master_category->id] = 
    $master_assets_this_category;
}
```

The group() scope keeps adding onto each loop so it results in something like...

```
group($master_category->id)->group($master_category->id)->group($master_category->id)->group($master_category->id)
```

With the $master_category->id being different with each loop. That makes the query return nothing since each Asset model has only one asset_group_id and all of the where clauses get chained with "and".

What can I use to remove the latest group() scope after each iteration so there is only the single current group ($master_category->id) scope used on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$asset_query` is an object. Instead of:

```
$master_assets_this_category = $asset_query->group($master_category->id)->get();
```

you should use here:

```
$master_assets_this_category = (clone $asset_query)->group($master_category->id)->get();
```

to have in each query only single `group($master_category->id)` scope instead of applying multiple scopes from previous iterations.

When using `clone` you will start always with the same object that you had before loop.

Comment: I had a feeling something like that existed - I tried several ways of getting that same effect but none of them worked. (clone) does work!
That's why I come here to ask...